# TypeError: expressValidator is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to do validations using express validator

**My app.js is as below**

```
//importing the express
const express=require('express');
//initializing the express
const app=express();
const morgan=require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

//mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:8080/mern",{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});

const postroutes=require('./routes/postsroute');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mern",{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("connected to mongodb");

});
app.use('/api',postroutes);
app.use(expressValidator());
app.listen('3030',() => {
   console.log("listening to port 3030");
});
```

**My express validator code is as below (which is added in separate file validators.js)**

```
    const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
exports.createostsvalidator=(req,res,next) =>{
    check('title',"title cannot be empty").notEmpty();
    check('title',"Title must be between 2 to 10").isLength({min:2,max:10});

    check("body","Body cannot be empty").notEmpty();
    check("body","Body should be min 5 and max 100 chars").isLength({min : 5,max:100});

    const errors = req.validationerrors();

    if(errors){
        const firsterror = errors.map((error)=> error.msg)[0];
        return res.status(400).json({error : firsterror});
    }
    next();
};
```

**My route is as below**

```
router.post('/createpost',validators.createostsvalidator,createpost);
```

Can anyone help with this what can be done

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `express-validator` doesn't work with `app.use`.

You need to use it like this

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

// in your route defintion
app.post('/user', [check('title',"title cannot be empty").notEmpty()], (req, res, next) => {});
```

see [this](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/735) thread for more info

Comment: its coming check is not a function, since validation is added in separate js file

Comment: in that case you need to require the `express validator` where you have your `check` call.

Comment: I have edited my answer. see the proper way of adding it.. It needs to be the second parameter while defining the route

Comment: As you suggested i included express validator and changed req.check to check(), now error coming as >TypeError: req.validationerrors is not a function, please see the updated code above

Comment: i dont want my route to have validations and req,res,next in route with code inside please

Answer (score 0):

1-First: Include This Code On Server.js File:

```
const {check} = require('express-validator');
```

2-Second Load This Code On Your Base Controller:

```
const {validationResult} = require("express-validator");
```

3-Third Write Method For Showing Errors

```
//Show Errors For Validation Rules
showValidationErrors(req , res , callback) {
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ message: errors.array(),success:false });
}
}
```

4-Forth Create A File With Name ValidationController.js On Your Controllers Folder With This Content:

```
const {check} = require('express-validator');
exports.register = [
check('name').notEmpty().trim().escape().withMessage('Name Should Be Write!').isLength({min: 5}).withMessage('Name Should Be Write With 5 Character!'),
check('email').notEmpty().isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Your Email Is Not Valid!'),
check('password').notEmpty().isLength({min: 5}).withMessage('Your Password Should Contains 5 Character')
];
exports.login = [
check('email').notEmpty().isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Your Email Is Not Valid!'),
]
```

5- Then Write These Cods On Your Route File:

```
const validate= require(`${ControllerApi}/v1/ValidationController`) 


router.post('/register',validate.register,AuthController.register.bind(AuthController));
```

6-  Finally For Showing Errors Write This Code On Your Controller:

```
if(this.showValidationErrors(req, res))
return;
```